# How to fetch the record when Query string with the single quotes string in Php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I am fetching data from the MySQL Database and database has a table name

**wp_evr_event**. I am fetching records using event_name  from **wp_evr_event**.

**wp_evr_event** table has a fiels name event_name that use name of event.

now event name is **Women\'s Reading Group** into database.

when I used the Query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE `event_name` LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['events_name']."%' ";

        echo $sql;
```

Query become like

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE `event_name` LIKE '%Women \'s Reading Group%'
```

But this is not fetching any record.

Comment: Does the event name literally has \  in it?

Comment: I think if you escape your input you should be fine ( what method you use? mysql, mysqli or pdo ?

Comment: See about parametrised queries.

Comment: @GurV  yes in database,value is :- Women\'s Reading Group

Comment: @ShahzadDitro have you tried my ans ?

Comment: @krishnpatel yes but result is empty

Comment: @S.Visser I am using wodpress Query:-$this->wpDb()->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

Comment: Then you should use the prepare function. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: I have updated my ans can you try now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the wordpress wpdb class you should use 2 functions. `esc_like` & `prepare`

A small example:

```
global $wpdb;

// First, escape the link for use in a LIKE statement.
$link = $wpdb->esc_like( $_REQUEST['events_name'] );

// Add wildcards
$link = '%' . $link . '%';

// Create a SQL statement with placeholders for the string input.
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE `event_name` LIKE '%s'";

// Prepare the SQL statement so the string input gets escaped for security.
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $link);
```

If you prepare your query like this you should get the expected result.